# Use apply() instead of FOR loop to create dictionary from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, apply

How can I achieve the same result as in script below, but using some function and apply()? I know about list comprehensions, but it's only apply() without loops acceptable.

```
x_dict = {}
for indx, row in df.iterrows():
    x_dict[indx] = df
```

I expected to get dict with keys, which is indexes of dataframe, with using some function and apply() without any loops and comprehensions. Is it possible?

Comment: You mean `df.apply()`? I can't think of a good way to do it with the built-in `apply()` function.

Comment: Right. The goal is to exclude loops from function witch makes some actions with df and forms dict with this new dataframes for every index of init df.

Comment: df.to_dict() doesn't work for you?

Comment: @crashMOGWAI This seems to be an academic exercise in using `df.apply()`. So whether some other function "works" is irrelevant.

Comment: What is the value of x_dict[indx] ? the whole `df` ?

Comment: df.to_dict()  just converts the DataFrame to a dictionary. In my case I need to obtain dict, where keys are the indexes of init df, and values are the new dataframes, rised from init df.

Comment: @norden87 Can you please update your question and put there specific input (small) and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do. If close, you can use these callouts to construct final product.

```
import pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(cola=[1,2,3,4], colb=[4,5,6,7]))
df.apply(lambda row: print(f'index={row.name}, data={row.to_dict()}'), axis=1)

index=0, data={'cola': 1, 'colb': 4}
index=1, data={'cola': 2, 'colb': 5}
index=2, data={'cola': 3, 'colb': 6}
index=3, data={'cola': 4, 'colb': 7}
```

If you're trying to build a json struct or something, you'll have to manually construct the dict

```
def update(row, x_dict):
    x_dict.update({row.name: row})
 
x_dict = dict()
df.apply(lambda row: update(row, x_dict), axis=1)

#x_dict[3] output 

|      |   3 |
|:-----|----:|
| cola |   4 |
| colb |   7 |
```

Comment: It’s not a dict) as I mentioned in my question the goal is to obtain the dict as reference script with for loop allows

Comment: Are you essentially describing the functionality of `df.iloc[n]` where n is anywhere in the range of your index ?

Comment: Yes, “n” must contain indexes of init df and must be the key of dict.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you are looking for:

```
x_dict = {}
def get_dict(x):
    x_dict[x.name] = pd.DataFrame([x.values], columns=x.index)
```

where `x.name` gives you the index in `apply` function and your result will be in `x_dict`.

OR if you want list as values in your dict.

```
x_dict = {}
def get_dict(x):
    x_dict[x.name] = x.values.tolist()
```

Then  use

```
df.apply(get_dict, axis=1)
```

and

```
print(x_dict)
```

Comment: Thx for reply. Output is not a dict which I obtain in reference script with for loop.

Comment: You cannot get a dict from `apply` which is what you say should use. `apply` returns a dataframe. Otherwise just use `to_dict()`.

Comment: I edited my answer. I think I understand now what you are asking. :) You have an external dictionary which you want to populate using apply and a function. Please try that edit.